# Get images uploaded to this post in popup on editor screen

Tags: images

I'm using the [ZillaSortcodes](http://www.themezilla.com/plugins/zillashortcodes/) plugin and add some functionality to build a shortcode to use the images uploaded to the post/page for an image grid.

In the shortcode.class.php of ZillaShortcodes I use this code to retrieve all images uploaded to the post

```
$referer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
preg_match('/post=(\d+)&/', $referer['query'], $referedID);
$actual_post = $referedID[1];

$attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_parent'      => $actual_post,
    'post_type'        => 'attachment',
    'numberposts'      => -1,
    'post_status'      => 'any',
    'post_mime_type'   => 'image',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'orderby'          => 'menu_order',
));
```

To get the post ID I have to be a little bit tricky and getting the ID from the URL. This works fine if the post/page is already saved and the shortcode popup [looks like this](http://www.dreihochzwo.de/download/zilla.jpg).

But this only works if the post is saved and there is a ID within the URL. Similar to the WordPress Media Manager where I can select "Uploaded to this post" I'm looking for a solution to get this to work even if this is a new post.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0):

### The post object is already available when you are editing a post.

if you need it just call `global $post`;

#### There is also a handy little core function that does this for you, [get_attached_media()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media)

```
// Get the images uploaded to the post
$images = get_attached_media( 'image' );
```

Comment: Oh, sorry - I should have mentioned that I have tried calling `global $post` and with the function `get_attached_media()`. But the result is always an empty array.